# How can i make custom Firebase rules for signin up with an email adress?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password) has predefined rules like for instance: "password lenght must be a least 6 characters".

is it possible to overide those rules and build custom ones and if yes how so ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to place additional constraints on accounts managed by Firebase Authentication.  You are always free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature) if you would like to see this, but there are no guarantees this will implemented.